A lemma about a full associative algebra
I'm reading the following book "Modern Geometry — Methods and Applications: Part I. The Geometry of Surfaces, Transformation Groups, and Fields, by Anatolij Timofeevič Fomenko e Sergej Petrovič Novikov", however I don't fully understand a lemma, the number 40.3.1, on page 432. The lemma is the following, we need do define first of all the following (Dirac)matrices:
$$
\gamma^0=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0  & 0 &0\\
0 & 1 & 0&0\\
0 & 0 & -1&0\\
0 & 0 & 0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\gamma^1=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0  & 0 &1\\
0 &0 & 1&0\\
0 & -1 & 0&0\\
-1 & 0 & 0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\gamma^2=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0  & 0 &-i\\
0 & 0 & i&0\\
0 & i& 0&0\\
-i& 0 & 0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\gamma^3=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0  & 1 &0\\
0 & 0 & 0&-1\\
-1 & 0 & 0&0\\
0 & 1 & 0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
The lemma recites: All of the 4 x 4 matrices $ \mathbb{I_4}, \gamma^a, \gamma^a \gamma^b(a <b), \gamma^a \gamma^b \gamma^c(a < b <c)$,
and $\gamma^5=\gamma^0\gamma^1\gamma^2\gamma^3 $, are linearly independent. It follows that $\gamma^0,\gamma^1,\gamma^2,\gamma^3 $generate the
algebra M(4, $\mathbb{C}$), and further that the relations (1) form a full set of defining
relations for that algebra. \
$$\gamma ^a\gamma^b+\gamma^b \gamma^a=2 g^{ab} \mathbb{I_4} \\g=  \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0  & 0 &0\\
0 & -1 & 0&0\\
0 & 0 & -1&0\\
0 & 0 & 0&-1
\end{bmatrix} (1)$$
What is $M(4,\mathbb{C}$) here? What is a full associative algebra (it is introduced in the book in the previous paragraph without a definition) in this context?

$M(4,\Bbb C)$ is the algebra of all $4\times 4$-matrices with complex numbers as entries. It is an associative algebra (full means, not only a subalgebra of $M(4,\Bbb C)$, but all of it).
